# calculate fee based on membership date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Players register at our events. I type their name in (`#P1`, `#P2`, etc.) and the function `getCCCRexpire(ele)` looks up their club expiration date. I want to modify function `calcEntryFee` to calculate the entrance fee. If the players expiration date is later than today, the fee (`#E1`, `#E2`, etc.) is `$3`. If the players expiration date is today or earlier, the fee is `$5`.

The problem is that the non-blank players with memberships expiring today or earlier don't get picked up. For example, `NAME = "Jones, John" MEMBERSHIP_EXPIRES = "2017.01.12"` should populate the  fee with `"$5"` but it just leaves it blank.

A second problem is the unnecessary complexity of the function `calcEntryFee`. I've never seen anything this advanced or frankly obfuscated. I would sure be grateful in someone could rewrite this function and make it work correctly. I am clearly in over my head. I'm not even close to a solution.

HTML

```js
function calcEntryFee(elem) {
  var idx, member, exDate, today, fee;

  elem = elem || {};
  if (/^[PEMX](\d+)$/.test(elem.id)) {
    idx = RegExp.$1;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  member = getMemberData(jQuery('#P' + idx).val());
  mmfee = parseFloat(jQuery('#M' + idx).val());
  exDate = moment(member.cccrEXP, 'YYYY.MM.DD');
  today = moment();
  fee = '';

  if (!member) {
    fee = 0;
  }
  //if ( (exDate.isBefore( today ) || exDate == 0) && P1 > "") {fee = 5; } // my attempt to solve the issue. 
  if ((exDate.isBefore(today) || !member)) {
    fee = 5;
  }
  if (exDate.isSameOrAfter(today)) {
    fee = 3;
  }
  if (member.cccrEXP == "" && mmfee > 0) {
    fee = 0;
  }

  // Updates the entry fee input value.
  jQuery('#E' + idx).val(fee);

  return fee;
}

function getCCCRexpire(ele) {
  var i = null;
  for (i = 0; cccr_mems.length > i; i++) {
    if (cccr_mems[i].Name == ele.value) {
      return cccr_mems[i].cccrEXP;

    }
  }
  return;
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
  $("#P" + i).on("blur", function() {
    $("#CCCR_X" + i).val(getCCCRexpire(this));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
<div>
  <div><input type="text" id="P1" onblur="calcEntryFee(this);" name="N1" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" onblur="getCCCRexpire()" name="cccr_exp" id="CCCR_X1" /> </div>
  <div><input type="text" name="ef-fee" id="E1" /></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div><input type="text" id="P2" onblur="calcEntryFee(this);" name="N2" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" onblur="getCCCRexpire()" name="cccr_exp" id="CCCR_X2" /> </div>
  <div><input type="text" name="ef-fee" id="E2" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example where people can see your issue. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://verlager.com/index.php click on folder and press tab to autofill. None of the expired date entrants will show $5 fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> rewrite this function and make it work correctly

(I forgot to say) Try this:

```
function calcEntryFee( ele ) {
    let id_num = ele.id.substring(1); // 2 if `id` is E2

    // If player name is blank, empties the "ef" field.
    if ( ! ele.value ) {
        $( '#E' + id_num ).val('');
        return;
    }

    let cccrEXP = getCCCRexpire( ele ); // expiration date
    // no expiration date
    if ( ! cccrEXP ) {
        // if membership fee > 0, fee is $0; else, it's $5
        let fee = $( '#M' + id_num ).val() > 0 ? 0 : 5;
        $( '#E' + id_num ).val( fee );
    } else {
        let today = moment(),
            expire = moment( cccrEXP, 'YYYY.MM.DD' );

        // expiration date is today or earlier; fee = $5
        if ( expire.isSameOrBefore( today ) ) {
            $( '#E' + id_num ).val(5);
        }
        // expiration date is later than today; fee = $3
        else if ( expire.isAfter( today ) ) {
            $( '#E' + id_num ).val(3);
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

1. Added the `fee` variable.
2. Checked the `ele.value`. If blank, empties the "ef" field.

Comment: I tried your code. It is at http://verlager.com/index.php But it doesn't show the $5 payments. Any idea why it doesn't ? Load the page, click the folder icon, go to first name and press and hold tab. See "Campbell" with a blank membership expiration date should show fee of 5 but it doesn't. (But I do appreciate your code which is easy to read and understand)

Comment: So if expiration date is blank, it should be $5 and not $0 like in my code? See the `// no expiration date, but membership fee > 0`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Except if the membership payment is >0.

Comment: If the membership payment is >0, then the fee is 0,

Comment: To be clear the term "fee" is the membership dues payment. The "ef" is the entrance fee which we are trying to calculate.

Comment: I tried it... it's very close. But the problem is that it shows $5 even for blank player's  names. If the player's name is blank, we need the ef to also be blank.

Comment: Ok, it should work well now.. try again? (the code may be longer now, but if you remove the comments, the code would be more compact..)

Comment: Spot on! You solved it. I have been working in this for hours without success.

Comment: I'm just glad to hear that, and thanks a lot for accepting my answer. =)